# Filtro SQL (Resultado que não deveria aparecer)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

é o seguinte estou criando um agendamento online e preciso listar os e mostrar os horários que não estão agendados, para mostrar os horários livres.
E para isso criei a tabela agendamento_horarios onde na coluna horarios_fixos fica a lista de horários, e na outra tabela a agendamento é onde fica os agendamentos e preciso que o valor que esteja na tabela agendamento_horarios no caso na coluna horarios_fixos, só apareça os horários que não foram agendados, e o problema que ta acontecendo que ta aparecendo exemplo:

Preciso que os valores de uma tabela com horários fixos não apareçam no select.

Os horários fixos são: 
02:00
02:10
02:20
02:30

Aí uma pessoa agendou o horário de 02:00 até 02:30, então os horários de 02:10, 02:20 estão aparecendo no select e não deveria.

segue o a consulta q fiz:

```
SELECT horariosfixos 
FROM agendamento_horarios 
WHERE horariosfixos NOT IN(SELECT horaInicio 
                           FROM agendamento 
                           WHERE data = '17-10-2016' 
                           UNION 
                           SELECT horaFim 
                           FROM agendamento 
                           WHERE data = '17-10-2016')
```

Se pudere me ajudar, fico grato.

Comment: Quando você faz uma busca NOT IN, você está fazendo uma busca exata. Está igualando os valores. No seu caso, acredito que você vá precisar usar o BETWEEN, para buscar entre dois valores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que esse SELECT possa te ajudar a resolver:

```
SELECT Ah.horariosfixos 
FROM agendamento_horarios Ah
LEFT OUTER JOIN agendamento Ag
  ON Ag.horaInicio <= Ah.horariosfixos 
  AND Ah.horariosfixos < Ag.horaFim
  AND Ag.data = '17-10-2016'
WHERE Ag.horaInicio IS NULL
```

Comment: Realmente já ajudou bastante, não mostrou os horários entre o agendamento, porém os horários após o agendamento também não mostra. Tipo 02:40 não aparece quando fiz o select e 02:30 no caso já que é o horário fim deveria aparecer pois apartir desse horário já poderia ta atendendo, mas muito obrigado Rick, mas é bem difícil essa lógica.

Comment: Editei a resposta removendo o "=" do where da horaFim. Talvez isso faça o 02:30 aparecer.

Comment: A lógica estava invertida. Pode ver se agora funciona?

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou esses ai:

Comment: só mostrou: horariosfixos
02:10:00
02:20:00
02:30:00

Comment: continuou a mostrar o 02:10

Comment: Editei novamente. Continua não funcionando? Esse campo `data` está com o dia 17/10 mesmo?

Comment: Ainda assim não funciona. Mostra os 02:10, 02:20 e 02:30

Answer (score -1):

Rick obrigado pela ajuda, depois que você me mandou o codigo que fez, me deu uma luz, e então montei o código e funcionou, segue ai:

> SELECT Ah.horariosfixos 
>   FROM agendamento_horarios Ah, agendamento Ag where ag.horaInicio<>ah.horariosfixos and ag.horaFim<=ah.horariosfixos